# Makefile generate numerical list of files

Tags: linux, bash, makefile

I have a Makefile that I use for building a book I am writing into EPUB and Kindle formats.

However, my list of source files is getting really long:

```
CHAPTERS = \
    1.md \
    2.md \
    ...
    30.md \
```

I am trying to generate this list programmatically, and I got it working with:

```
CHAPTERS = $(addsuffix .md, $(shell seq 1 30))
```

But can't help but feel I feel like there is a simpler way.

Is there a simpler method to achieve numerical file generation (i.e. can this be reduced to a single command instead of 2 nested commands)?

Comment: `$(shell printf '%d.md\n' {1..30})` should work in Bash but it IMHO not at all more elegant or readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coincidentally, the [GNUmake Table Toolkit](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) features such a function:

[$(call interval,start,range[,step])](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt#call-intervalstartrangestep)

```
$(call interval,5,5) --> 5 6 7 8 9
$(call interval,2,3,100) --> 2 102 202
```

Of course, *simple* is just a relative measure...

Comment: At least it removes the `shell` dependency. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a simpler method to achieve numerical file generation

You can do without shell. Whether it's simpler or not...

```
mygen=$(words $3)$1 $(if $(word $2,$3),,$(call mygen,$1,$2,w $3))
CHAPTERS:=$(call mygen,.md,30,w)
```